# Filtering a dataframe showing only duplicates

Tags: r, filter, duplicates

I need some help to filter a dataframe.

The df has several columns and I want to split it into two dataframes:

1- One including only the rows in which the first column is a duplicate (including all of the replicas).

2- The rest of the rows, which are not duplicates.

Here is an example:
This would be the original.

```
          V1  V2 
    [1,] "A" "1"
    [2,] "B" "1"
    [3,] "A" "1"
    [4,] "C" "2"
    [5,] "D" "3"
    [6,] "D" "4"
```

I want to turn into this:

```
         V1  V2 
   [1,] "A" "1"
   [2,] "A" "1"
   [3,] "D" "3"
   [4,] "D" "4"
```

And this:

```
        V1  V2 
  [1,] "B" "1"
  [2,] "C" "2"
```

Is there a way to do that? I have tried exporting to Excel, but the dataset was too large to make that viable.

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible data set, and the desired result? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: For the first part you could use base::duplicated()

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Considering `df` as your input, you can use `dplyr` and try:

```
df %>% group_by(V1) %>% filter(n() > 1)
```

for the duplicates

and

```
df %>% group_by(V1) %>% filter(n() == 1)
```

for the unique entries.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `duplicated` but bear in mind that `duplicated` only returns `TRUE` at the first duplicated value, i.e.

```
> duplicated(c("A", "A", "A"))
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

does not return `TRUE` for the first `"A"`. If you want to catch all values of `"A"` you can e.g. use

```
duplicated(c("A", "A", "A")) | duplicated(c("A", "A", "A"), fromLast = TRUE)
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

You can then separate your data using

```
## Index of the duplicated values:
indDuplicatedVec <- duplicated(d[,1]) | duplicated(d[,1], fromLast = TRUE)

myDuplicates <- d[indDuplicatedVec, ]
myUniques <- d[!indDuplicatedVec, ]

> myDuplicates
#V1 V2
#1  A  1
#3  A  1
#5  D  3
#6  D  4

> myUniques
#V1 V2
#2  B  1
#4  C  2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[.N >1], V1]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

`d[!duplicated(d),]`

and

`d[duplicated(d),]`

where `d` is your database.

=== UPDATE ===
If only the first column is desired, and all duplicates need to go in a separate column, you could do:

`library(gdata)
d[duplicated2(d$V1,bothWays = T),]
d[!duplicated2(d$V1,bothWays = T),]`

If only base R is desired, then:

`bm <- duplicated(d$V1) | duplicated(d$V1,fromLast = TRUE)
d[bm,]
d[!bm,]`

Comment: It is not working. Using that code, the new datasets will not have both of the values of D, for instance.

I want a code that makes possible getting the same original dataset if i rbind the 2 split dataframes again.

Comment: The problem here is that you're considering all the columns. Also, OP does not want to retain any instances of duplicated columns in the unique set.

Comment: Oh, I see. There was no example in the original version of the question. I will edit the answer